# Merge .AppleDouble forks with original files

Tags: macos, nas, rsync, metadata, hfs+

I used to place my *iTunes*’s media folder on a NAS accessed through **AFP** and, as you may know, the OS also placed several *.AppleDouble* files on it.

Now, my NAS isn’t working as expected and the only ways that I have to access/recover my songs—and other data stored on it—are:

- `rsync` them through SSH (this seems to work except for some files).
- Disassembly/unbrick the NAS and try to access the Ext4 filesystem with a SATA-to-USB adapter; borrowed to replace the firmware from a Live (linux) distro (it doesn't solved the problem).
- Pay for a professional data recovery service.

Now the actual problem:

I have used `rsync` in order to copy the Media folder to an external hard drive whose file system is **HFS+**; now how can I merge the *.AppleDouble* files within the original files?

Or should I get rid of them without any problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the rsync option that preserves extended attributes, that is the -E option on the Apple supplied version of rsync, then the files will be joined automatically on the HFS+ filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to another question https://superuser.com/a/1173246. Basically, you need the `FixupResourceForks` utility which is a standard part of MacOS (although not on the normal `PATH` — it's in `/System/Library/CoreServices/`.)